# Replace mixed escape sequences, control characters and literals with Sed?

Tags: sed, escaping, control-characters

I have a weird mix of literal, visible and escaped control characters in a data dump that I need to clean (preferably with *sed*), for example **^A**, **^B**, **\N** (literally), and visible newlines. I need to clean the file such that the visible newlines remain intact, replace every ^A with a tab character, and strip every **^B\N^B\N** (which follows every unix time value in the data e.g. 13068505731812510).

This is what the contents look like using `less` in a shell command (in the shell, the **^A** and **^B** characters have a dark background to denote control chars):

> **^A** guid **^A** unix-time **^B\N^B\N^A** 4 **^A** 192.168.21.136 **^A** 7.0 **^A** IE **^A** 8 **^A** guid **^A** WinNT **^A** ... (visible newline)

Or a literal example...

```
... ^A40C4595C-0B9D-46B7-8214-3D9CE2B5F057^A13071154505579551^B\N^B\N^A4^A192.168.21.136^A7.0^AIE^A8^AE6979203-F58B-4D20-9D66-7F5369BF9E32^AWinXP^A ...
```

So far the escape sequences I've been feeding *sed* have not been producing the expected output. Does anyone know the magic escapes needed to make all this happen in as few passes as possible? (There are many gigs of files, and time counts.) Thanks! Bonus points if I can convert the unix time digits into human-readable times in the same pass.

Answer (score 0):

Change ^A to tabs:

```
sed 's/\^A/'"$(printf '\011')"'/g'
```

Strip our ^B^N:

```
sed -e 's/\^B\\N\^B\\N//g'
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try these & report back. I had unsuccessfully tried `sed 's/\^A/\t/g'` - any idea why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Ok, so far _sed_ isn't cooperating with replacing control characters like ^A (or if it is, at least it's not evident using less, and I've tried replacing `^A`, `\^A`, and `\001` with `\t` and with the printf command).

Comment: We need to see some version numbers, OS, shell, sed? Good luck.